# Why doesn't the .clone copy my div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with my site on which I am trying to clone a div to add it to every nth article. (http://trollfutbol.tumblr.com/)

I have added a script that adds adWrap div to every 7th article.

```
$('article:nth-child(7n)').replaceWith('.adWrap').clone();
```

And it does clone it and it adds the ad to the 7th but then the ad won't re-add itself to the 14th article etc. It only adds the wrapping.

Any ideas?

the html is basically

```
<div class="content">
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>          regenerating infinite times (as many posts I will have)
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <div class="adWrap">ad iframe</div>
</div>
```

Comment: [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) does not modify the DOM. Beside that the `.clone()` is called on the elements that are returned by [`.replaceWith('.adWrap')`](https://api.jquery.com/replacewith/), which `[...] return the set of elements that was removed.`

Comment: You're probably looking for `$('article:nth-child(7n)').replaceWith(function() { return $('.adWrap').clone(); });`

Comment: Can you post cleaned up sample markup for the `<article>` element? Would help with debugging.

Comment: @Kita is this what you meant?

Comment: @adeneo It didn't change anything, it just went to the 7th but didn't copy to the 14th etc.

Comment: @t.niese But the articles that were #7 #14 etc was removed when I checked and didn't get cloned. Also as I have positioned the ad at the end of my page it has clearly been copied from the end to the place of the 7th article.

Comment: Calling `.clone` clones the element and returns these elements, but the cloned elements are **not** added to DOM. As I said only calling `.clone` on a jQuery result set has no effect on the DOM, you need to add the result of a `.clone` to the DOM yourself.

Comment: @RichardLundWinther yes. Using that markup with your original code (`$('article:nth-child(7n)').replaceWith('.adWrap').clone();`) inside of a `$(document).ready(function(){});` replaced every 7th element with contents of  `.adWrap`: http://jsfiddle.net/74063d9e/

Comment: @t.niese aahh, I see! Is there no way of getting around this? to make it regenerate the result again?

Answer (score 2):

Little mistake - missed parentheses to replaceWith command and variable character - dollar.

Correct js code is

```
$('article:nth-child(7n)').replaceWith($('.adWrap').clone());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kbqcr9vw/2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add $ and Parentheses to this you might also want to add :eq(0) I dont know how replaceWith acts when multiple elements are found

```
$('article:nth-child(7n)').replaceWith($('.adWrap:eq(0)').clone());
```